# How to add labels dynamically to nodes in Neo4j from neo4j-ogm or spring-data-neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

When I create a node, I want to add multiple labels, known at run-time, to the node. Is it possible to this in neo4j-ogm or spring-data-neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't supported in the current version but is on the roadmap.

Comment: Yes supported in OGM 2.0.5 http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/tutorial/#runtime-managed-labels

Comment: Hi @Luanne, is it possible to dynamically set the `@OGM\Node( label = "DYNAMIC__NAME" )`?

Answer (score 0):

Add some dependences

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Create an Enitity with lombok accessors

```
@NodeEntity
@Data
public class Content{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id; //Internal Neo4j Identifier. DONT TOUCH

    // Your Bns Logic identifier
    private Long myId

    @Properties
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    @Labels
    private List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

A Repository for your Entity

```
public interface ContentRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Content, Long> {
}
```

A simple controller to add your labels and properties in the Node

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ContentController {
    @Autowired
    ContentRepository contentRepository;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Create a Node", notes = "create a node", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Success", response = String.class)
    })
    @PostMapping("/api/content")
    public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> createNode(@RequestBody MyDTO requestWrapper ) {

        //Create Database Entity from DTO
        Content content = new Content();

        //Add Labels
        content.getLabels().addAll(requestWrapper.getLabelList());
        //Add properties
        requestWrapper.getHmap().forEach((k,v)->content.getProperties().put(k,v));

        try {
            contentRepository.save(content);
            requestWrapper.setId(content.getId());
        } catch (Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity< MyDTO >(requestWrapper, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```